# django, name 'IndexView' is not defined

Tags: django, django-urls

I am following [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial/). At the moment I am at [this](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial/#registering-new-users-checkpoint) point but when I start my server with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and open the url in my browser, I receive following Error:

```
name 'IndexView' is not defined
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns

from rest_framework_nested import routers
from authentication.views import AccountViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, since I never saw myself even declaring this `IndexView` somewhere. It would be awesome if you guys could give me some suggestions on this one.

Edit:

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets

from authentication.models import Account
from authentication.permissions import IsAccountOwner
from authentication.serializers import AccountSerializer

class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.'
        }, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Have you declare any other *main* view? Show your folders tree and `views.py` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create that `IndexView` and import it in your `urls.py`.
Currently the interpreter complains since in the `urls.py` `IndexView` is unknown. 
To create a new view you should create a new class in `views.py`, something like:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

ps: please read the official Django docs, which is very good!

Comment: I think the confusion stems from when these types of classes are not referenced anywhere in the tutorial. For example, on this site it would be useful to reference exactly what you just stated perhaps one time: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#term-application-namespace

Answer (score 2):

The IndexView class is in the boilerplate project's views file.

C:\...\thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate-release\thinkster_django_angular_boilerplate\views

Copy and paste that content into your project's views file.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your urls.py

```
from .views import IndexView
url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

(.views or yourProject.views)

in your views.py
do what daveoncode wrote