# Trouble with Django urls

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm new to Django and using version 1.9.8. I followed the official tutorial, and now I'm trying [this](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#registering-new-users) more advanced one. I'm at the end/checkpoint of the "registering users" section. When I visit `http://localhost:8000/register`, Django is displaying the content I have on my index.html page located at `authentication/templates/authentication.html` rather than the one created during the tutorial at `static/templates/authentication/register.html`.

When I initially got to where I am, I was receiving the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'IndexView'`, referencing the urls.py

```
#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns

from rest_framework_nested import routers
from authentication.views import AccountViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'), #this line was causing the error
]
```

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287331/django-name-indexview-is-not-defined) from someone else who was following the same tutorial. I added the IndexView import to my urls.py as such

```
from authentication.views import AccountViewSet, IndexView
```

And then I added an IndexView class to my views.py

```
# authentication/views.py
....
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'mytestproject/index.html' #this page is showing when I visit http://localhost:8000/register rather than the one located at static/templates/authentication/register.html
```

The IndexView error went away and the server ran without errors, but when I visited  `http://localhost:8000/register` nothing was being displayed. I opened up that index.html page and added content, and then it displayed that content. Django is clearly using the index file located at `authentication/templates/authentication.html` instead of the register page I created. How do I get Django to use the template located at `static/templates/authentication/register.html` when I visit the register url? I'm confused, mainly because no methods named 'register' were defined in the view during the tutorial, nor designated in the urls.py file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

`.*` in  `'^.*$'`, tells any url will go to this IndexView

and

you did'nt add url for your register page in url.py

```
url(r'^register/',views.yourview,name='givenameforthisurl')
```

Comment: That's the part that I'm confused about. As far as the tutorial goes, no "register" methods were created server side in views.py.  What view & name am I giving that URL? The only thing related to register I created is the template located at `static/templates/authentication/register.html`. Does this mean the tutorial is missing content, or is there something I'm not understanding? Are they possibly relying on angular's routing to access that template? After all, it was placed in the static folder.

Comment: yes you need to write view function to display a page ,or if you use django's inbuilt views you just only need to import those packages in url.py , [see this example for inbuilt "authentication views"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)